# Variable not getting the info assigned to it

Tags: javascript

When I use this code the `musicData` comes out `undefined` even though I set it to `metaData`. Also, I know `metadata` has info in it.

```
let musicData;
for(i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
  queueString += i + 1 + ": `" + queue[i] + "`\n";
  mm.parseFile(config.MUSIC_DIR + queue[i]).then( metadata => {musicData = metadata;});
  console.log(musicData);
}
```

Comment: Is this inside an async function? If so, you can await `mm.parseFile`. Otherwise, you cannot assign the result to `musicData` like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

If you try to return musicData variable from for loop it always shows undefined.
So Good to serch how to return data from for loop.
if else try to use musicData variable inside the for loop.

like that

```
for(i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) 
{
   let musicData;
   queueString += i + 1 + ": `" + queue[i] + "`\n";
   mm.parseFile(config.MUSIC_DIR + queue[i]).then( metadata => {musicData = metadata;});
   console.log(musicData);
}
```

Comment: Why does this resolve the issue?

Comment: The reason is because the for loop has an exit point controlled by a boolean variable. It doesn’t need a return statement, which is only to be used in a body of a function.

Comment: The reason I ask is because `mm.parseFile` is a promise so its `then` could be run after `console.log(musicData)`. So I'm confused as to what resolves the issue. --- (This is why the question has been marked as a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

Try for..of loop with await in it

```
let musicData;
let index = 0;
(async () => {
  for (const element of queue) {
    index++;
    queueString += index + ": `" + element + "`\n";
    await mm
      .parseFile(config.MUSIC_DIR + element)
      .then((metadata) => (musicData = metadata));
    console.log(musicData);
  }
})();
```

Comment: This throws an error in Firefox: _"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ( after for"_